# Как экранировать символ $ в XML тэгах?

Tags: xml, экранирование

У меня есть документ в **xml**.
В нем, условно есть тэг:

```
<code>1а$3</code>
```

То есть, на третьей позиции кода стоит знак доллара. Некоторая программа, которая парсит **xml**-документ, выкидывает исключение - $ - не допустимый знак, исправьте его.
Исправлять - долго, нужно дёрнуть сопутствующие файлы.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли как нибудь экранировать $, чтобы слово в тэгах было прочитано именно как **1a$3**?

Comment: Знак доллара $ является допустимым символом для XML. Проблема в программе (*...Некоторая программа...*), которую вы используете.

Comment: Ну можно попробовать `&#xx`;